# Bundling provisioning profiles with iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'd like to enable push notifications for distribution on the app store. I've gone through the process of creating a provisioning profile, and app id that has a bundle identifier the same as the app that is also enabled for push notifications, etc. However, after I do this on the apple developer website, how do I get the provisioning profile into the app to be submitted? Is it enough to just update my XCode account preferences with the provisioning profile, and then submit it through XCode? Or is there something else I have to do?

Also, if I'd like to get this same process to work with an .ipa file, what would I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling push and updating your provisioning profile, download it and double-click to install it locally. Back in Xcode, verify that the new (or updated) provisioning profile is selected and you should be good. You can select different profile for development and distribution builds, just be sure to select the ones you want.

Once selected, the provisioning profile will be used by "archive" when creating and exporting an .ipa file.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how do I 'select' a provisioning profile? Do I do that through the account preferences page?

Comment: This is done in Xcode. Go to the "Build Settings" tab and look for the "Code Signing" section. There you can set the provisioning profile for both debug and release builds.

Comment: I see this area now, thanks. However, I'm only able to select code signing identities? I'm not able to select the provisioning profile that has push enabled for it? I did associate the provisioning profile with one of these code signing identities so is that how they are linked?